# L'H with functional equation

Tags: limits, functional-equations

I am working on learning limits, and I decided to create a derivative of a function, convert it to a limit, and try to solve it as a limit.

Here's my equation: $$\lim_{d \to 0} \frac{2\sin(x+d)-\sin(x)-\sin(x+2d)}{d^2} = f(x)$$

By the way, I know $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

My first idea is to do L'Hopital's Rule, but I don't know how to do that with a limit on $d$ going to $0$ and a $x$ doing... nothing. I have tried multiple things, both of which screw up the limit to not be $\sin(x)$. Does anyone know the correct way to apply L'H to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use L'Hopitals rule, and since $x$ is doing nothing... treat it as a constant, while differentiating w.r. t. $d$.

\begin{align}
{\rm L} &=\lim_{d \to 0} \frac{2\sin(x+d)-\sin(x)-\sin(x+2d)}{d^2} \\
&=\lim_{d \to 0} \frac{2\cos(x+d)-2\cos(x+2d)}{2d}\\
&=\lim_{d \to 0} \frac{-\sin(x+d)+2\sin(x+2d)}{1} \\
&= 2\sin x-\sin x\\
&=\color{blue}{\sin x}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Been there, done that. It didn't work unless I really did it wrong. Show me how that would work, and I'll check if it's still $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Rdr Easy. Done.

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes to accept this. Thank you, though!

Edit: was right. Sorry.

Comment: Forgot chain rule @Rdr ? Derivative of $\sin 2d $ is $2 \cos 2d$ similarly $$(\sin (2d+x))'=2\cos (2d+x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using l'Hospital only once:

$$\begin{aligned}
& \lim_{d \to 0} \frac{2\sin(x+d)-\sin(x)-\sin(x+2d)}{d^2} \\
&= \lim_{d \to 0} \frac{\cos(x+d)-\cos(x+2d)}{d} \\
&= \lim_{d \to 0} \frac{-2\sin\left(\frac{(x+d)+(x+2d)}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(x+d)-(x+2d)}{2}\right)}{d} \\
&= \lim_{d \to 0} \frac{-2\sin\left(x+\frac{d}{2}\right)\sin\left(-\frac{d}{2}\right)}{d} \\
&= \lim_{d \to 0} \sin\left(x+\frac{d}{2}\right) \cdot \frac{\sin\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}{\frac{d}{2}} \\
&= \sin(x)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Using lh once, is that something to be so proud of?

Comment: @KingTut I typed it just for fun and for refreshing my memory

Comment: I meant no harm. I have rather liked your answer.

Comment: @KingTut Thanks for your comment.  As Landau's notations are commonly used in journals, now I prefer egreg's approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor expansion at $x$:
$$
\sin(x+d)=\sin x+\frac{\sin'x}{1!}d+\frac{\sin''x}{2!}d^2+o(d^2)=
\sin x+d\cos x-\frac{d^2}{2}\sin x+o(d^2)
$$
Hence
$$
\sin(x+2d)=\sin x+2d\cos x-2d^2\sin x+o(d^2)
$$
and finally
\begin{align}
&2\sin(x+d)-\sin x-\sin(x+2d)\\
&\quad=2\sin x+2d\cos x-d^2\sin x-\sin x-\sin x-2d\cos x+2d^2\sin x+o(d^2)\\
&\quad=d^2\sin x+o(d^2)
\end{align}
yielding
$$
\lim_{d\to0}\frac{2\sin(x+d)-\sin x-\sin(x+2d)}{d^2}=
\lim_{d\to0}\frac{d^2\sin x+o(d^2)}{d^2}=\sin x
$$

Comment: Overcomplicated much? This looks really confusing and is much more complicated than the above answers. Also, where did $o$ come from?

Yet another gripe: I cannot follow this at all. Some of these conclusions seem out of left field. If you could explain this better, I would appreciate it more.

Comment: @Rdrpenguin This is standard language for Taylor expansions; you cannot do limits without knowing it.

Comment: Isn't it lh in disguise

Comment: @KingTut The other way around …

Comment: Yeah that's truer.